# Death and birth process and proportion

Tags: r

I have this code which describes a death and birht procceses with four states, 0,1,2,3.

```
bd_process <- function(lambda, mu, initial_state = 0, steps = 100) {
time_now <- 0
state_now <- initial_state

time <- 0
state <- initial_state

for (i in 1:steps) {
if (state_now == 3) {
  lambda_now <- 0
} else {
  lambda_now <- lambda
}
if (state_now == 0) {
  mu_now <- 0
} else {
  mu_now <- mu
}
time_to_transition <- rexp(1, mu_now + lambda_now)
if (runif(1) < mu_now/(lambda_now + mu_now))  {
  state_now <- state_now - 1
} else {
  state_now <- state_now + 1
}   
time_now <- time_now + time_to_transition 
time <- c(time, time_now) 
state <- c(state, state_now) 
}
return(list(time = time, state= state))
}
```

From this code I want to create a function which count the proportion of time in each time. The function is aimed to take two parameters, and Im a bit lost. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example function that identifies the times for each state and sums them. It uses `sapply` to iterate over the possible states.

```
x=bd_process(2,3)
#' @param x a list returned by bd_process function
#' @return a vector of times spent in state 0,1,2,3
get_times=function(x) {
  sapply(0:3, function(i) {
    sum(x$time[which(x$state==i)])
  })
}
get_times(x)

[1] 401.52405 607.44447 253.52741  38.58117
```

Comment: thank you! im supposed to the proportion so I guess i have to divide with something, right?

Comment: Right, forgot about that part. This should work: `prop_times=function(x) {
  totals=sapply(0:3, function(i) {
    sum(x$time[which(x$state==i)])
  })
  return(totals/sum(totals))
}
prop_times(x)`

Comment: Thank you, it kind of works! But I want to get the time between each change of transition w